# Fix Drupal\Core\File\Exception\NotRegularDirectoryException: is not a directory. in Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem->scanDirectory()

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

After adding this to *sites/default/settings.php*

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';
```

This is the error my website shows, but I am unsure how to fix it:

```
*Drupal\Core\File\Exception\NotRegularDirectoryException: is not a directory. in Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem->scanDirectory() (line 665 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php).*

Drupal\ui_patterns\Plugin\Deriver\AbstractYamlPatternsDeriver->fileScanDirectory() (Line: 188)
Drupal\wingsuit_ui_patterns\Plugin\Deriver\LibraryDeriver->getPatterns() (Line: 61)
Drupal\ui_patterns\Plugin\Deriver\AbstractPatternsDeriver->getDerivativeDefinitions(Array) (Line: 101)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives(Array) (Line: 87)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 285)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 72)
Drupal\ui_patterns\UiPatternsManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 52)
Drupal\ui_patterns\UiPatterns::getPatternDefinitions() (Line: 23)
ui_patterns_layouts_layout_alter(Array, NULL, NULL) (Line: 539)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->alter('layout', Array) (Line: 334)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->alterDefinitions(Array) (Line: 289)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 168)
Drupal\Core\Layout\LayoutPluginManager->getThemeImplementations() (Line: 28)
layout_discovery_theme(Array, 'module', 'layout_discovery', 'core/modules/layout_discovery') (Line: 469)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->processExtension(Array, 'layout_discovery', 'module', 'layout_discovery', 'core/modules/layout_discovery') (Line: 356)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->build() (Line: 255)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->get() (Line: 88)
Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->initializeRegistry() (Line: 69)
Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->__construct('theme_registry:runtime:dxpr_theme', Object, Object, Array, 1) (Line: 275)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->getRuntime() (Line: 194)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->getBuildDefaults(Object, 'full') (Line: 61)
Drupal\node\NodeViewBuilder->getBuildDefaults(Object, 'full') (Line: 157)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->viewMultiple(Array, 'full', NULL) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->view(Object, 'full', NULL) (Line: 41)
Drupal\webprofiler\Entity\EntityViewBuilderDecorator->view(Object, 'full') (Line: 102)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Controller\EntityViewController->view(Object, 'full') (Line: 66)
Drupal\node\Controller\NodeViewController->view(Object, 'full', NULL)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 564)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 158)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 80)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 38)
Drupal\webprofiler\StackMiddleware\WebprofilerMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

When looking at line 665 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php this is what I get

```
line 664: if (!is_dir($dir)) {

line 665: throw new NotRegularDirectoryException("$dir is not a directory.");

line 666: }
```

What does this mean? I am very very very new to drupal and don't really know much about how to interact with PHP files. I started getting the "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." message after installing various modules, I believe after installing [Gutenberg](https://www.drupal.org/project/gutenberg) this happened...

I have also cleared the cache by adding this line to sites/default/settings.php

```
$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;
```

Grateful for any help.